# The case of equality for $a\leqslant b_1$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I understand the following is true, for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ if $a\leqslant b_1$ for any $b_1 > b$, then $a<=b$. However since we can use any $b_1$, then I want to consider the case that $a = b_1$. If this is true, then it turns out that we get $b < b_1 = a$ which is contrary to $a<=b$. Why is this the case?

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb R$. Show if $a\le b_1$ for every $b_1>b$, then $a\le b$.

Comment: This is true, Look at the textbook "Elementary Analysis: Theory of Calculus" by Kenneth A. Ross- Exercise 3.8

Comment: Like what exactly?

Comment: There is a proof in the text for a theorem where they say "for any"

Comment: Yep, it says "to prove $\alpha <= L$, then it suffices to show that $\alpha <= L_1$ for any $L_1 > L$", where $\alpha$ and $L$ are both fixed since they are the limsup of 2 different sequences. It may be a typo they may have not caught in their errata page.

Comment: whatever - changing the word "every" to "any" was a bad idea, the ultimate source of your confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this corrected version, you have $a$ and $b$ fixed, and you are assuming $a \leq b_{1}$ for **every** $b_{1} > b$. So if $b_{1} > b$, you cannot have $a = b_{1}$, because there will be a value $b_{1}^{\prime} \in (b,b_{1})$ with $a \leq b_{1}^{\prime} < b_{1}$.

Answer (score 2):

If I were in charge the word "any" would be banned from mathematical discourse, because "for any $x$" can be read as "for some $x$" or "for every $x$".

Please note I'm not insisting that both of those readings are correct, so the "any" is formally ambiguous. I'm just claiming that it *does* get read in both of those ways. And here in this thread we have proof of that: the corrected version of the question shows that the OP changed "for every $b_1$" to "for any $b_1$", and the counterexamples that have appeared in comments and deleted Answers are clearly reading it as "for some $b_1$".

So the word has to be banned, because it *is* ambiguous in practical terms: given that people *do* read it both ways, surely some authors intend it this way and some intend it that way, and the reader has no way to tell which (unless as here one version is *obviously* false...)